# SOQL query to find every Friday of month

Tags: apex, soql

Am a trying to find a way to query every Friday of a month passed in to my apex controller. So say we're looking at March, I want my query to return data from the 3rd, 10th, 17th, 24th and 31st. I see that there is a

```
DAY_IN_MONTH()
```

function, but this returns the number in that month and not the day itself. Is there an easy way to do this?

Follow up question: How could I create a list of Dates with the passed in month's Fridays. So this would have either 4 or 5 elements each call. I am making a Lightning cmp table header and would like the headers to be the 4 -5 friday days for the selected month but am finding this difficult.

Comment: Ask your separate question in a separate post.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as how that function can be used in a query, it would look something lie:

```
SELECT Id FROM MyObject__c WHERE CreatedDate = THIS_MONTH
AND DAY_IN_MONTH(CreatedDate) IN (3, 10, 17, 24, 31)
```

However, you could instead use `DAY_IN_WEEK` and save yourself the trouble of calculating which dates you need:

```
WHERE DAY_IN_WEEK(CreatedDate) = 6
```

Note that `1` represents `Sunday`, and `7` represents `Saturday`. Since `Saturday - 1 = Friday`, you should use a value of **`6`**

If you wanted to query records created on Fridays in a particular month/year, it would look like:

```
public static List<MyObject__c> getRecordsCreatedFriday(Integer year, Integer month)
{
    return [
        SELECT ... FROM MyObject__c
        WHERE CALENDAR_YEAR(CreatedDate) = :year
        AND CALENDAR_MONTH(CreatedDate) = :month
        AND DAY_IN_WEEK(CreatedDate) = 6
    ];
}
```

You could also add an overload that accepts just a date within the month to filter:

```
public static List<MyObject__c> getRecordsCreatedFriday(Date dateInMonth)
{
    return getRecordsCreatedFriday(dateInMonth.year(), dateInMonth.month());
}
```

It might just be worth reading up on *all* **[Date Functions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_date_functions.htm)**.

Comment: Oh man I did not see the DAY_IN_WEEK function. This is great. One follow up Q: If i wanted to create a List of Dates with that months friday's only, could I use this? EDIT: Updated above

Comment: @Angelo If you had `List<Date> fridays`, you could just do `DAY_ONLY(CreatedDate) IN :fridays`. Not sure exactly how to interpret your follow up question.

Comment: If your Salesforce org has a different Start of Week, will this still work?

Comment: @JeremyNottingham Unlike the `Datetime` documentation, which explicitly mentions locales, the documentation on Date Functions does not say anything about it. I take that to mean it does not vary, but it's a good separate question.

Comment: @AdrianLarson - Under the hood is there a performance hit using this function or does SF store that day of week value in the underlying table? I would think they store it to improve performance otherwise it would require a full table scan right? I **Just Checked** it does require a full table scan so would be best to add indexed fields to the query to reduce cost. Without index filters the cost is like 1.9 (In my org) which is bad.

Comment: @Eric Interesting observation. Definitely something to keep in mind if applying these functions against a large table. How large was the table on which you ran that query plan? Did you also filter on year and month?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `DAY_IN_WEEK()` method with the value `6` for Friday:

```
SELECT Id FROM MyObject__c WHERE DAY_IN_WEEK(CreatedDate) = 6
```

Comment: Sorry. I badly read the documentation....